# How to read multiple Kafka topics with Spark into seperate Dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spark-kafka-integration

I am publishing data to 2 afka topics name "akr" and "akr2". How can I read them in separate dataframes?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Spark + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) and assuming ou plan to process them with Structured Streaming you can define the required two Dataframes as below:

```scala
val df1 = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "akr")
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

val df2 = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "akr2")
  .load()
  .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
```

The data of the two mentioned topics will be consumed as soon as you have some Spark *actions* on the Dataframes.